# Bidirectional USB Type C charging

Tags: power-supply, bidirectional, usb-c

Recently I bought a ready PCB that is basically a power bank when 18650 batteries are connected [This](https://rover.ebay.com/rover/0/0/0?mpre=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.co.uk%2Fulk%2Fitm%2F282654655352). It has a micro USB port to charge the 18650s and two USB type A one of which output is 1A and the other 2A. I also bought a USB Type C breakout board [The female one](https://rover.ebay.com/rover/0/0/0?mpre=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.co.uk%2Fulk%2Fitm%2F253187170065). Now, I try to convert that power bank to support Type C. I want it to be bidirectional. So when it detects external voltage at the Type C port to switch to charging mode and apply that voltage to the micro USB connections. But when there is no external voltage at the Type C port it will output voltage from the 2A Type A port. Can that be done with the use of simple electronic parts? If not what components sould I search for? I tried to find documentations on USB Type C on the Internet on that topic but I cannot find what I want.

Answer (score 1):

The USB Type-C doesn't work as you described. The load of ideas how the port should opreate (as dual-role port) is described in the original USB Type-C specifications, which are freely available from USB.org, as part of [entire USB 3.2 zipped package](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/usb_32_112017.zip).

Initially none of Type-C port will have any voltage on VBUS, so you can't use it as detector who is provider, and who is consumer. The role of a port is determined by pulls (up or down) on CC pins. And the CC wire goes from one port to linked port over C-C cable. Once the right combination is established and recognized, the source will put out VBUS, and the consumer will take it. For details please examine Section 4 of Type-C specifications, all variants of connectivity are pictured there.

Comment: Hi, link is broken

Comment: @PathToLife, the link will lead you to "USB library". Unfortunately, specific links to specific documents get changed due to document revision change, but you should be able to navigate yourself through the library.